# Rails devise Deletes user from database after logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, destroy

I have a problem with my devise gem. When I log out with a user, devise deletes my user out of my mysql database. I recognized this error first on yesterday, before it was working. I don't remember what register and login is also still possible.

User Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @user }
end
end

def destroy
@user = User.find(params[:id2])
  @user.destroy
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_url}

end
end

end
```

Logout-Link

```
<%= link_to  " Logout", destroy_user_session_path(:id2 => current_user.id), :class => "btn  btn-danger icon-share-alt ",:style=>"font-family: FontAwesome;font-weight: bold;color:black", :method => :delete  %>
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
rolify
belongs_to :ressourcen

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

attr_accessible :vorname, :nachname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :roleid,:id

validates :email, :uniqueness => true
```

Answer (score 1):

That seems really weird.  If devise and routes are setup in a default way, I can't see how this should happen.  What does:

```
rake routes
```

show you for destroy_user_session_path?  If you haven't overridden devise's SessionsController, and haven't changed devise's routes, the only entry for destroy_user_session should look something like this:

```
destroy_user_session  DELETE  /users/sign_out(.:format)  devise/sessions#destroy
```

It definitely shouldn't be going to your UsersController at all.  It should be going to devise's SessionsController.

In any case, this logout link works for me:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

destroy_user_session_path shouldn't need the user id.  It's only destroying the user in the session, so there is no need for an id.

UPDATE:

When you log out, what page are you returned to? If you haven't defined the SessionsController yourself and haven't overridden after_sign_out_path(), it should try to return to root_path. If you don't have root defined in your routes, it will return to "/". Can you confirm from your log file (e.g. development.log) exactly what happens when you click on the 'logout' link? Which actions are called and when/what SQL queries are called? Just when you click on the link, not when you later browse to look at users. Also, what does the devise_for line in your routes.rb look like?  It's worth digging in to exactly what is happening when you only click on the logout link.

As far as I know the only thing inside devise which could delete a user from the database is RegistrationsController.destroy() which would be called if a DELETE request was sent to /users (with no id). It would find the currently-logged-in user from the session (which is why it doesn't need an id) and destroy them. In the standard devise views, it looks like this can only be called from devise/registrations/edit.html.erb and presumably you aren't doing this.

Comment: `destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                   devise/sessions#destroy`

destroy_user_session was using GET-Path.. I changend it, but it also doesnt work. The user controller still finds no user.

Comment: See my updated answer; hopefully there are a couple of helpful pointers there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you customize/override the devise sessions controller?

If not your logout link should probably look like this:

```
<%= link_to  " Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :class => "btn  btn-danger icon-share-alt ",:style=>"font-family: FontAwesome;font-weight: bold;color:black", :method => :delete  %>
```

Devise doesn't know what the `:id2` param is.

Comment: Unfortunaly this doesnt work, too. I also think I dont have a session controller... Just a User_controller. When i use "destroy_user_session_path" without parameters, how does the controller find the user?

Comment: Take a look at the [session controller source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb).  It calls [sign_out here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/sign_in_out.rb).

Devise knows the current_user

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
destroy_user_session_path
```

with this:

```
destroy_session_path(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

And than in **SessionsController** destroy your session. This way you are destroying your user every time someone click on logout link.

Comment: "Couldn't find User with id=sign_out"

Comment: Somewhere you are passing "sign_out" to User.find function. Try running rake routes in console and see where is **destroy_session_path** taking you.